# How can I set the content type of a newly created Java File object?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, s3fs

I'm moving a video from one area to another(s3fs), so I'm doing it as so:

```
File newFile = new File(newFilePath);
```

then copying using this code

```
FileUtils.copyFile2(file, newFile);
```

But in S3, my object content type is wrong. How can I also set the content type to "video/mp4" during this process? Or even before?

thanks for the help.

Comment: Except by convention, in most file systems, files don't have any metadata associated with them saying what their content type is, they just have a file extension (which is the convention I was talking about). (The old Mac OS file system format was an exception to this rule.) The file is just data, and software is expected to figure out what the format of that data is. Web resources have a content type associated with them, which is usually done by the web server involved, but not files in a file system.

Comment: I guess to be more specific... for some reason these files aren't being recognized as video/mp4, but previously they were. This could be amazon, but I used to be able to just copy a file like this and video/mp4 was what it was recognized as.

Answer (score 0):

s3fs should set Content-Type based on the file extension from `/etc/mime.types`.  Does your file name match ones of these line?  Otherwise is should be possible to force Content-Type when setting `-o ahbe_conf` and providing a file of the form:

```
.mp4 Content-Type video/mp4
```